# How to ask question in meta.stackoverflow

Tags: support, meta

I asked question [93841](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93841/how-can-i-to-add-a-js-library-to-code-in-jsfiddle) which was closed as off topic. Looking back at it, I see that the title was a poor choice. The title is "How can I to add a js library to code in jsfiddle?" However, the first line of the question is "I want to provide code for a question in stackoverflow."

Jsfiddle was recommended to me in a stackoverflow response. I thought I was asking for help doing what was recommended: to use jsfiddle to provide code when I asked a question in stackoverflow. I also thought meta was the place to ask for help with writing questions.

So I am again asking for help with a question. How could I ask this question, which I intended to be about posting in stackoverflow, and if not here, then where should it have gone?

To avoid misunderstanding, please note that I am not trying to be argumentative. I am trying to understand how to ask about asking questions.

Comment: Hmm.. you asked this one just fine, no? :P

Answer (score 4):

Your previous question was in a gray area.  You were sincerely asking a question that you thought was **about asking a question** and the logical place for such questions is meta.  But the specifics of the question are about a site that is **not directly related** to Stack Overflow.

If you had asked the original question on SO you might have been sent here.  If you asked the question here, you might be sent to SO.  In order to successfully ask your question, you can try to rephrase it so that it is unambiguously appropriate to SO or to MSO, otherwise it has the potential to be misunderstood.

To ask your question on SO, you can simply leave out or tangentially mention that your question is about asking a question, e.g "Adding external resources on jsfiddle."

To ask your question on MSO, you can change the question so that it only about asking questions, e.g. "Using jsfiddle to ask questions on Stack Overflow."

Looking at these two modified questions, it looks like the SO question would be the most useful for the original problem you were experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) outlines what kinds of questions should be asked here as

If your question is **about**:

```
Stack Overflow
Stack Exchange Area 51
The core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites
```

… it is welcome here.

your original question would have been better suited for stackoverflow or programmers exchange